# Network Suggestions - current setup diagram provided

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vnc, afp

I have my home network setup like this:

[image: My Network]

I'd like any  suggestions on the setup in general. Specifically I'm looking for suggestions on how to open up AFP access to my NAS from the internet. I'd like to open up VNC access to my Mac Mini from the internet as well. I would like to keep all other internet access closed off to my network. The Time Capsule is my DHCP server at the moment. All wired connections have an assigned lease to keep the IPs static, with the exception of the PS3. The Guest wireless network is turned off 99% of the time, I turn it on when company needs access to the internet from their laptop.

I know the Time Capsule has some port forwarding capabilities but haven't looked into it much yet, specifically I'm not sure if I can forward to different IPs based on the port. Should I at this point get a dedicated firewall or is the Time Capsule as a gatekeeper enough?

My wireless - in my own opinion - seems slow to me when i transfer files to my NAS from the laptop, an recommendations on how to speed that up would be nice as well.

Additional, reasonably priced, hardware can be purchased if needed.

*A side note: I can build my own solutions involving Linux and script and whatnot, but I much prefer plug-and-play solutions at this point in my life.*

Comment: Define "slow" for your NAS-to-laptop communications.  The only weakness I see currently is that the Time Capsule Router is a bottleneck.  It's got to handle all the data to and from the Internet as well as the NAS.  I don't know what the internal transfer rate of a Time Capsule is, but it might help if you had a dedicated AP instead of a combined unit.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing your NAS and VNC, you would need to enable port forwarding. I don't own a router from Apple, but it looks like you can set this up following this guide if you need (first result on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=port%20forwarding%20time%20capsule&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)):

http://must-know-mac.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-port-forward-time-capsule.html

AFP Port: 548 (tcp)

VNC Port: 5900 (tcp & udp). That port should work with Mac OS X, but VNC also exists on 5500 (tcp) and 5800 (tcp) if 5900 doesn't work.

Slow WiFi might be due to a poor location of the Time Capsule, interference, or you might need to restart it (works for my Linksys router sometimes).

As far as your other questions go, I'm not too much of an expert on it. I do think your Time Capsule would work fine, but I'm no expert on security.